Issues with siunitx, and longtable percentage column
On the line of some other tables I made, I have attempted to use the same approach for this one. However, in this case I have three columns with different type of numeric entries. The first one is a five integer/four decimal column, the second is a five integer column and the last one a percentage.
I'm attempting to wrap everything in a \siunitx cell type repeated twice, as I'm comparing some metrics across two approaches, but for some reason I'm prompted with an error related to c column which I cannot really pinpoint.
Also, is there a way to have the percentage sign printed in the last column with the R2 correlation?
Below the code that should provide a MWE. Let me know, thanks in advance!
\documentclass[12pt]{report}


\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,siunitx}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\smallerbaseline}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{%
    @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    >{\centering\arraybackslash\smallerbaseline\bfseries} l *{2}{{S[table-format=5.4]}{S[table-format=5.0]}{S[table-space-text-post=\si{\,\%}\ ]<{\,\%}|]}}
}
\caption[\textbf{Key parameters for the \texttt{ABC-RF} multiple dispersal model.}]{\textbf{Key parameters for the \texttt{ABC-RF} multiple dispersal model.} \dots}
\label{table:param_est} \\
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{APPROACH}} \\
\cmidrule{2-7}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{linear reference}  
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{pangenome graph} \\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7}

& {\textit{expectation}} & {\textit{median}} & {\textit{R}} & {\textit{expectation}} & {\textit{median}} & {\textit{R}} \\
\cmidrule{2-7}

tdOA1 & 62684.7791 & 57826 & 46.18 & 58110.1077 & 54272 & 46.18\\
tdOA2 & 49040.5162 & 46917 & 24.25 & 47795.5630 & 46030 & 24.25 \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}

P. S. I've taken the last \siunitx from here but just realized they use tabular instead of longtable...

Off-topic: (a) If you want the longtable environments to fully span the width of the textblock, don't forget to also issue the instructions \setlength\LTleft{0pt} and \setlength\LTright{0pt} before \begin{longtable}. (b) Instead of overburdening the arguments of the \caption statements with \textbf directives, just load the caption package with the additional option textfont=bf. (c) For crying out loud, please replace >{\centering\arraybackslash\smallerbaseline\bfseries} l with >{\smallerbaseline\bfseries}c.

@Mico noted. Indeed, very helpful suggestion (a) now I can finally have my tables spanning the whole \textwidth. Noted also the comment in (b). Regarding your last point (c), however, I have a questions. Unfortunately, due to my inexperience I kind of learned it by heart and sort of understood what it was doing based on the Q&A I open here in the past. So the question is how the {\smallerbaseline\bfseries}c is more efficient, maybe something at the compiler level as in (b)? Let me know, thanks again!

On point (c): It's not a matter of efficiency. Is the purpose of  >{\centering\arraybackslash}l to center-set the cell contents? Well, LaTeX doesn't work that way.  Try compiling the following test document: \documentclass{article} \usepackage{array} \begin{document} \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}l|} ldkjfal fjdal \\ dfal \end{tabular} \end{document}. Observe that the cell contents are not centered but, rather, left-aligned. Hence my recommendation to switch from >{\centering\arraybackslash}l to c.

In your example, there was an extra set of {} around each S type column and the third S type column was missing its table-formatoption.

\documentclass[12pt]{report}


\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,siunitx}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\smallerbaseline}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{%
    @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    >{\centering\arraybackslash\smallerbaseline\bfseries} l 
    *{2}{S[table-format=5.4] %
         S[table-format=5.0] %
         S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\unit{\percent}]<{\unit{\percent}}}%
    }
\caption[\textbf{Key parameters for the \texttt{ABC-RF} multiple dispersal model.}]{\textbf{Key parameters for the \texttt{ABC-RF} multiple dispersal model.} \dots}
\label{table:param_est} \\
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{APPROACH}} \\
\cmidrule{2-7}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{linear reference}  
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{pangenome graph} \\
\cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}

& {\textit{expectation}} & {\textit{median}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{R}} & {\textit{expectation}} & {\textit{median}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{R}} \\
\cmidrule{2-7}

tdOA1 & 62684.7791 & 57826 & 46.18 & 58110.1077 & 54272 & 46.18\\
tdOA2 & 49040.5162 & 46917 & 24.25 & 47795.5630 & 46030 & 24.25 \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{%
    @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    >{\centering\arraybackslash\smallerbaseline\bfseries} l 
    *{2}{S[table-format=5.4] %
         S[table-format=5.0] %
         S[table-format=2.2]}%
    }
\caption[\textbf{Key parameters for the \texttt{ABC-RF} multiple dispersal model.}]{\textbf{Key parameters for the \texttt{ABC-RF} multiple dispersal model.} \dots}
\label{table:param_est} \\
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{APPROACH}} \\
\cmidrule{2-7}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{linear reference}  
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{pangenome graph} \\
\cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}

& {\textit{expectation}} & {\textit{median}} & {\textit{R in \unit{\percent}}} & {\textit{expectation}} & {\textit{median}} & {\textit{R in \unit{\percent}}} \\
\cmidrule{2-7}

tdOA1 & 62684.7791 & 57826 & 46.18 & 58110.1077 & 54272 & 46.18\\
tdOA2 & 49040.5162 & 46917 & 24.25 & 47795.5630 & 46030 & 24.25 \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}


\end{document}


sweet, thanks a lot I definitely missed out those... thanks for the insight about the percentage style for the column as well! Love the first option that gives me the freedom to add the superscript to the R for the correlation.
